# Yii2: Set incorrect username or password message on login

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am using yii2 basic for my application. When I login to my application by typing wrong username or password, it does not set any message like incorrect username or password. The browser simply refreshes the page.

This is my **site/login.php** file:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model app\models\LoginForm */

$this->title = 'Login';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-login">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to login:</p>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox([
        'template' => "<div class=\"col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3\">{input} {label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
    ]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

   <!--  <div class="col-lg-offset-1" style="color:#999;">
       You may login with <strong>admin/admin</strong> or <strong>demo/demo</strong>.<br>
       To modify the username/password, please check out the code <code>app\models\User::$users</code>.
   </div> -->
</div>
```

And here is my action for login:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $model->password = md5($model->password);
            $model->login();
            return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a custom message error in your rules.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'required', 'message' => 'Please choose a username.'],
    ];
}
```

It creates a JavaScript vaidation and shows the error in `message` if validation was wrong.

See [Validating Input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html) and `Customizing Error Messages` section.

**EDIT:**

If you are using the basic app, make sure that your **LoginForm.php** has the login form calls `validate`. Something like this:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**This is from the advanced template but is similar.**

Comment: You might want to modify your answer stating that you actually have to enable the client validation for the javascript to work (it gives the impression right now that it just does). Also the OP doesn't call the validation function in the action so might be handy to mention that too.

Comment: If he use basic app, `$model->login()` should validate.

Comment: Seems you are correct. Sorry for that. But I would still add the remark about the client validation option :)

Comment: I think the OP means something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245083/no-error-message-when-login-fail-yii2

Answer (score 2):

The `if ($model->load())`-statement does no validation at all. It simply determines if the form in question was POSTed and that the POST data was loaded into the form instance. I'm assuming that the `login()` function returns a `bool` so you'll have to check its return result as well:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->password = md5($model->password);
        if ($model->login()) {
           return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
        } 
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

<strike>If the login function correctly uses the `model::addError()` function it should then also display errors.</strike>

The `login`-function of the basic application does run the validation, as @Sageth pointed out, so the change I proposed will work as expected.

Comment: can this be possible through javascript validation?

Comment: Pretty much anything is possible, you just have to write the code for it. Yii doesn't do that out of the box if that is what you are referring to.